# Any Favorites/ Bookmark file plugin for Gedit 3.12 +?

Tags: gnome, gedit, plugins

I want to bookmarks files in Gedit so that I can open them easily later. There are some [old](https://github.com/Quixotix/gedit-favorites/) plugins which used to work for older versions. But is there any working plugin for Gedit 3.12+.

I am using Gnome shell 3.10 on Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 . Gedit version is 3.12.2

Thanks